# Find the parent of a given key in Binary Tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to find the parent of a given key in binary tree (not BST). This code always returns null, can someone tell where is the problem? I think the problem is even if I return parent, it will still return null.
Thanks :)

```
public Node getParent(int key,Node parent, Node r){
    if(r!=null){
        if(r.iData==key)
            return parent;
        getParent(key, r, r.leftChild);
        getParent(key, r, r.rightChild);
    }
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are recursing into the left and right subtree but when these calls find a match you just ignore it. Instead do something like

```
public Node getParent(int key, Node parent, Node r) {
    if (r!=null) {
        if (r.iData == key)
            return parent;
        Node p;
        p = getParent(key, r, r.leftChild);
        if (p != null)
            return p;
        p = getParent(key, r, r.rightChild);
        if (p != null)
            return p;
    }
    return null;
}
```